# VBA Goal Seek Multiple Rows

Tags: excel, vba

This should be simple I just can't wrap my head around it

I have 3 columns

A   B   C
I want to run a goal seek on B and C if A has data in it

Range("B3").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("C3")

I want something similar to this:

```
  If CellA>0:
     Range("D1").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("C1")
```

This could be some 7000 lines worth if that makes any difference

Comment: what's the question? is it "determine if an excel cell has data in it"? If so, pls change title.

Comment: No sorry if i wasn't clear. Basically if cell A1 has data, then goal seek D1 and C1. This would continue through A2, D2 , C2 .... to A5000,D5000, C5000 etc...

Comment: @Mitch Wheat No sorry if i wasn't clear. Basically if cell A1 has data, then goal seek D1 and C1. This would continue through A2, D2 , C2 .... to A5000,D5000, C5000 etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim rCell As Range

For Each rCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Resize(, 1)
    If rCell.Value <> "" Then
        rCell.Offset(, 3).GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=rCell.Offset(, 2)
    End If
Next rCell
```

This code sample is based on your last comment above. It will change the cell in column C to give 0 in the formula in the D column.

Comment: In your comments you say if A1 has data in it. But in your code you are saying if A1 is grater than 0.  If the latter is true then use `If rCell > 0 Then`